# how to create a function that automaticaly retrives phone numbers from firebase database and replace to react native Linking.url(`tel:${phoneNumber}

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning to make the Backend for a React Native application using Firebase.
The app I am making requires the call a phone number that has been registered in firebase.

If I add the number manually in the IDE, it looks like this.

onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('tel:082394900558');}

But I need the phone number to be replaced with the numbers on the database, since there will be many users using the app.

It should look something like this..
onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('tel:"PhoneNumber"');}

So How do I get the phone numbers from the database and link it in openURL??
Please Help, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

depend on what firebase db type you are working with firestore or realtime database,

for firestore you would have to get the specific document with number like this using firestore library in react native -

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

// Get user document with an UserID of ABC
const userDocument = firestore().collection('Users').doc('ABC');
```

then get phone number by destructuring the user details object like

```
userDocument.phoneNumber // pass that into linking
```

passed to Linking like -

```
onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('tel:{userDocument?.phoneNumber}');}
```

incase of firebase realtime database fetching values will look something like -

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const userDocument = database().ref('/users/123');
```

rest in-terms of passing the value to Linking will be same as mentioned above.

Comment: do hit upvote if my answer helps !